# What would be the URL equivalent of my WebService Login

Tags: api, web-services

I need assistance on how get the full URL of code below (object parameter). I tried to run the

*http://192.168.1.1:80/api/APILogin/Login?username=admin&encryptedPassword=J+2eQXsuMp5mUBUlBqdkjg==*

but it doesn't work.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/APILogin")]
public class APILoginController : ApiController
{
    public APILoginController()
    { }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Login")]
    public Object login(LoginRequestCredentials userRequest)
    {

    }
}
```

This is the LoginRequestCredentials object.

```
public class LoginRequestCredentials
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string encryptedPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you call the URL with **Get** Method, and the Route is **HttpPost**

Comment: I used POST in the URL using Postman App.

Answer (score 0):

this url `http://192.168.1.1:80/api/APILogin/Login?username=admin&encryptedPassword=J+2eQXsuMp5mUBUlBqdkjg==` will be ok if you use route like this

```
public Object login(string username, string encryptedPassword) { ... }
```

but your route waiting for one object so send data in **BODY**

```
{
    username: "admin",
    encryptedPassword: "J+2eQXsuMp5mUBUlBqdkjg=="
}
```

---

**or** send in url

http://192.168.1.1:80/api/APILogin/Login? **userRequest.** username=admin&**userRequest.** encryptedPassword=J+2eQXsuMp5mUBUlBqdkjg==

**without spaces**